# JMeter soap response - data analysis

Tags: regex, web-services, soap, jmeter, data-analysis

I am doing some data analysis on address data. The data for the analysis is to be generated calling soap web service which returns soap response. 
In each soap response I am interested only in specific field i.e. 'matchType' in the example shown below. 'matchType' can have multiple occurrences maximum upto 20.
I have 500 addresses for which I get 500 responses similar to the one shown below. I am using JMeter to fire 500 soap requests to the web service.

Problem

```
How I can create the final results in CSV file containing 500 records that looks like
Addressline1, MatchType1, MatchType2 ... MatchType20
```

For above fields
Addressline1 to get from SOAP request
MatchType to get from SOAP response

If there is no MatchTypeN it leaves blank.

e.g. CSV file looks like this

10 Main Street, building, street, , , , , , ... , (upto 20th MatchType)
Park Avenue, building, building, building, ... , (upto 20th MatchType)

SOAP Request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:sch="http://website.com/WebService/Schema/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <sch:AddressRequest>
      <AddressRequestDetails>
        <lookupCriteria>
          <houseName/>
          <addressLine1>10 Main Street</addressLine1>
          <addressLine2></addressLine2>
          <addressLine3></addressLine3>
          <region/>
          <county>New York</county>
          <country/>
        </lookupCriteria>
      </AddressRequestDetails>
    </sch:AddressRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SOAP Response

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <ns2:AddressResponse xmlns:ns2="http://website.com/WebService/Schema/">
        <AddressResponseDetails>
            <location>
                <matchType>building</matchType>
                <locationCoordinates>
                    <xCoordinate>111111.111</xCoordinate>
                    <yCoordinate>222222.222</yCoordinate>
                    <coordinateSystem>ABC</coordinateSystem>
                </locationCoordinates>
            </location>
            <location>
                <matchType>street</matchType>
                <locationCoordinates>
                    <xCoordinate>333333.333</xCoordinate>
                    <yCoordinate>444444.444</yCoordinate>
                    <coordinateSystem>DEF</coordinateSystem>
                </locationCoordinates>
            </location>
        </AddressResponseDetails>
    </ns2:AddressResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the following:

1. Extract `matchType` response values and store them to JMeter Variables
2. Write these variables to CSV file

For point 1 I'd suggest to use [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) post processor.

Relevant Xpath expression would be

```
//ns2:AddressResponse/AddressResponseDetails/location/matchType/text()
```

After that you'll need to write the output to a file. The best option is to use [Beanshell Post Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

Assuming that you used `matchType` variable in XPath Extractor you should get something like

```
matchType=building
matchType_1=building
matchType_2=street
matchType_matchNr=2
```

All above are JMeter variables.

So following Beanshell code should do the trick for you:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.csv",true);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int matchCount = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("matchType_matchNr"));

sb.append("10 Main Street");
sb.append(",");
for (int i=1;i<=matchCount; i++)
{
    sb.append(vars.get("matchType_" + i));
    sb.append(",");

}
sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
out.write(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: vars.get("matchType_matchNr") doesn't seem working. I had to create 20 extractors like

Comment: ...continuing previous comment
//AddressResponseDetails/location[1]/matchType
//AddressResponseDetails/location[2]/matchType
//AddressResponseDetails/location[3]/matchType

and so on.

Comment: If you remove index `[1]` `[2]` etc from your XPath you'll be able to use single expression to extract all match types as in my example. You can use Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination to see what are matches. Besides JMeter 2.11 provides XPath Tester in View Results Tree.