# Append to a file in Groovy in Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

To log the total time of a test scenario I use Groovy scripts in JSR223 PostProcessors to capture the timestamp before and after the script.

Script to capture the scenario start timestamp:

```
def scenario_start = System.currentTimeMillis().toString();
vars.put("scenario_start", scenario_start);
```

When I want to append the results for one Customer I want to append the results to an output file using a second groovy script:

```
def scenario_end = System.currentTimeMillis().toString();
def scenario_start = vars.get("scenario_start");
def cm = vars.get("CUSTOMER_NUMBER");

log.debug("scenario_start = " + scenario_start);
log.debug("scenario_end = " + scenario_end);
log.debug("CUSTOMER_NUMBER = " + cm);

File file = new File("logs/output/scenario_times_idtv.txt").newOutputStream().withWriter { out ->
    out.append(cm + ";" + scenario_start + ";" + scenario_end);
}
```

The actual results is the first line in my log: scenario_times_idtv.txt is overwritten each time.

I've used `out.append`, `out.println`, `new File("...").withWriter {...}`, `new File("...").newOutputStream().withWriter {...}` but I get ONE line of data each time in my log.

I can't find how to properly APPEND new results to the log file.

Thanks for your experienced input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very Groovy expert, but recall answering something similar at [JMeter soap response - data analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534418/jmeter-soap-response-data-analysis/)

using [Beanshell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell).

I guess that if you change your code line

```
File file = new File("logs/output/scenario_times_idtv.txt").newOutputStream().withWriter { out ->
out.append(cm + ";" + scenario_start + ";" + scenario_end);
```

to something like:

```
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("logs/output/scenario_times_idtv.txt", true);
file.append((cm + ";" + scenario_start + ";" + scenario_end).getBytes());
file.flush();
file.close();
```

your script will behave as expected. Mind the `true` parameter of FileOutputStream. It tells  the stream to append existing file. Perhaps there is a Groovy analogue, but this bit should work as well.

Comment: I've edited your answer with the final code that worked fine! Thanks for steering me in the right direction Dmitri!

Answer (score 0):

What worked best for me was to set up the output file in a setUp thread group as a property (so it will be global across all thread groups), then use it within my main thread group, and close it out in a tearDown thread group.

setUp:

```
def fileName = vars.get("CSVFileName");

def currDate = new Date().format("_yyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss")
fileName = fileName.replace(".csv",  currDate + ".csv");
FileOutputStream fileLOG = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true);
fileps = new PrintStream( fileLOG );
fileps.println("user,otherCSV headers...");

props.put("MYLOGPRINTSTREAM", fileps);  // Properties are global to JMeter, so can be used to communicate between threads and thread groups
```

then in the main thread group:

```
def fileps = props.get("MYLOGPRINTSTREAM");
fileps.println(vars.get("user") + "," + other CSV fields ...);
```

and in the tearDown:

```
def fileps = props.get("MYLOGPRINTSTREAM");
fileps.close();
log.info("***TEARDOWN DONE*** ");
```